# Why my donut icing surface not reflecting light

Tags: lighting

I have been following Blender Guru's doughnut tutorial up to Part 7, and i am unable to identify why my doughnut icing surface doesn`t reflect even the slightest of light. Here's doughnut  in my rendered view mode looks like this  [image]

And this is how Blender guru's looks like  this[image]

(Note: i have already applied roughness like what he explains in the video but that doesn't work on it, and Fyi, i am using Blender 2.79 version)

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Is there a reason why you're not using the latest Blender version?

Comment: Well,it is because my windows 8.1 only support 32 bit while the requirement needs to be 64 bit ( only blender 2.79 acceptable to my system)

Comment: What do you mean with "applied roughness"? Would you mind sharing a screenshot of your material setup? That's more explanatory then just the render result. The render looks like the surface is fully rough and not reflective (of course this also depends on the viewing angles between camera, surface and light source).

Comment: hello please pack the images (File > External Data > Pack All Into .blend) and share your file: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: are u using rendered view?

Comment: @Chris Yes, because the _Material Preview_ doesn't show noise... and it's not the final render because the 3D cursor is visible.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann sorry for the confusion, what i trying to say is not " i applied roughness" but " i increasing or decreasing value of my icing's surface roughness that doesn't work on it"

Comment: @Chris yes i am using rendered view mode to explain my problem

Comment: So I have to agree with moonboots. 

Comment: @moonboots i have following your instruction( File > External Data > Pack All Into .blend) but after that , there is notification in my blender says "No new files have been packed". What does it mean?

Comment: oh don't worry, maybe you're not using an image, just share your file as it is

Comment: @moonboots so i just need to upload it by using https://pasteall.org/blend/?

Comment: Yes, upload and copy paste the URL it will generate

Comment: https://pasteall.org/blend/0dd02e1da4ec4aec8e4e6fd346e61dde

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably because you are using 2.79 while he's using 2.8 or above in his tutorial. The recent versions of Blender will use the *Principled BSDF* node by default instead of a simple *Diffuse*, and the *Principled BSDF* will create a bit of glossiness on the surface (and also a bit of *Fresnel* from what I remember). The simplest way to recreate a bit of glossiness it to mix your *Diffuse* with a *Glossy* node (open the *Shader Editor* window and press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> > *Shader* > ... to create these nodes). As you see with my setup there is not a big difference.

Here is the default material setup since 2.8 (since Principled BSDF):

[image]

If I replace it with a mix between *Diffuse* and *Glossy* nodes it almost the same as you can see. Note that you need to set a good lighting if you want to come close to what Blender Guru shows:

[image]

Comment: well it worked, even though the glossiness is little bit not bright as i wanted  in Blender Guru`s one  .. Thanks

Comment: I've just tested and my setup for 2.79 is about the same as Guru's result, you just need to move your light a bit

Comment: yeah i just need to test which direction my lighting suits me the most...  Thanks for your help